# How to Change Keymap for Opening Nested Context Menu?

Tags: customization, shortcut

When you <kbd>RMB[image: RMB]</kbd> (or press <kbd>W</kbd> if you have right-click to select) on an object you get a context menu, then <kbd>RMB[image: RMB]</kbd> again on certain commands (regardless of <kbd>LMB[image: LMB]</kbd> or <kbd>RMB[image: RMB]</kbd> to select) you get a nested context menu with commands like, E.g.:

- Add to Quick Favorites
- Assign Shortcut
- Online Manual

My question is: **how can the keymap for bringing up this nested context menu be set?**

The reason I'm doing this is that I have modified all context menus to be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>LMB[image: LMB]</kbd> to match the default behavior for Mac/OS X context menus for use with a tablet and pen where the pen buttons are not being used.

I have not been able to find a way to change the keymap to open this secondary context menu.